# Where we can get inline action info for buy ram contract?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, ram

when we invoke buyram contract to buy some rates, it will call inline action for transfer ram fee. 
I can see the buyram action on block, I don't see inline action on that. my question is that where I can see the inline action detail for a transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$ cleos get transaction 3995b76ea762c93798b54a7642fa65d49211dadfc1773340cad2e74b178f5510
```

and you'll see the trace in `['traces']['inline_traces']` including the `eosio.ramfee` transfers.